# PostgreSQL | JSONB: get the first path value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-14

Given a JSON input:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "street": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Anytown",
        "state": "CA"
    },
    "phone": 1234567
}
```

Is it possible (if so and how? I could not managed to do so) to get the first exists path's value.

I've tried: `select jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb_data, '$.address.region', '$.phone')` hopefully it will returns `1234567` without any success.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?  The third argument to jsonb_path_query_first needs to be of type jsonb, which '$.phone' clearly isn't.  And even if it were, what the heck would you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalesce():

```
select coalesce(
         jsonb_data #>> '{address,region}', 
         jsonb_data #>> '{phone}'
       )
from the_table;
```

Or using a JSON path:

```
select coalesce(
          jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb_data, '$.address.region'), 
          jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb_data, '$.phone')
       )
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, there is any favor solution regarding memory in case `jsonb_data` could be very large?